# Auto-balance Long Titles

Tags: sectioning, titles

Does `titlesec`, or perhaps some other package or macro, provide a way to auto-balance long titles. (I do now want to manually break the titles because in some other page size the current form may not need to broken.)

[image]

Comment: Well, how do you define a balanced title? *Then* it might be doable to define an algorithm.

Comment: I left the {titles} tag because this applies to titles as well.

Answer (score 2):

You want a raggedright that only allows a limited amount of stretch so TeX's usual paragraph breaker has to distribute it over the paragaraph `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e` would probably work but here I set it directly. It should be in a class file of course I do it mid-document to compare with the original.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textwidth{10.5cm}

\begin{document}
\section{The Purposes and Uses of Convention Cards}
zzzz zzz

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries
% all copied from article.cls except
\parfillskip=0pt
\rightskip=0pt plus .5\textwidth
\emergencystretch=.3\textwidth
}}
\makeatother

\section{The Purposes and Uses of Convention Cards}
zzzz zzz



\end{document}
```

Comment: How to use your solution for book sections (chapter, section, etc.)? Looking at book.cls I think I figure out to duplicate your answer for sections, but I am not sure about the chapter part.